# Can KVM be enabled (-enable-kvm) when running qemu without -cpu host

Tags: qemu, kvm

can KVM be enabled (-enable-kvm) when running qemu without -cpu host ?
e.g.

```
 qemu-system-x86_64  \
-boot c -m 16G -vnc :0 -enable-kvm  \
-cpu qemu64,avx,pdpe1gb,check,enforce \
...
```

Does QEMU use the KVM when running virtual QEMU64 CPU ?
I always thought that this option can be enabled ONLY when using qemu with -cpu host...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, running a guest with KVM acceleration (`-enable-kvm` option in qemu command line) can be done without `-cpu host`.

In the case of `-cpu qemu64,avx,pdpe1gb,check,enforce` qemu will set the union of the virtual `qemu64` cpu and `avx,pdpe1gb,check,enforce` features as cpu features for this guest. This is done by calling KVM's `KVM_SET_CPUID2` ioctl.

When the guest will ask for cpu features, it will receive these from KVM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this documented anywhere ? And also, what is the benefit of using -cpu host flag ?

Comment: "-cpu host" means "give the guest the same kind of cpu the host has", which means it will have all the features your hardware supports. For some people and use-cases, that's what they want. For others, they want the guest CPU to have only a specific subset of those features (eg so they can migrate the VM to a different host system later); those people pass a different -cpu option.